# Writing embedded javascript code to c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, winforms

i have the js file how can i add that in winform C#,
i have developed the front-end and i want to run the js file on button click.
i will be thankful to u if u provide the snippet!!!!!
I want to run javascript code in windows form
thank you.

Comment: It's not at *all* clear what's going on here, in terms of ASP.NET and Windows Forms being involved at the same time. Please give a lot more detail.

Comment: What are you trying to do with javascript that is causing you to want to run it from a winform?

Comment: what does "building a web site" have to do with winforms?  How are winforms involved at all!?

Comment: you need to provide more detail and context to your question. Validation in WinForms using javascript?? No. Sounds more and more like you're building a WebForms app, in which client-side validation using javascript is commonly used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cscript.exe to execute JScript on windows & can capture the output from the stdout.

```
string output;
using (Process cscript = new Process())
{
    // prepare the process
    cscript.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    cscript.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    cscript.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    // RedirectStandardOutput should be True to get output using the StandardOutput property
    cscript.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cscript.StartInfo.FileName = "cscript.exe";
    cscript.StartInfo.Arguments = "<Path to your .js file>";

    cscript.Start();
    output = cscript.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    cscript.Close();
}
```

**Obviously your JScript cannot contain any statement that is illegal on windows**

for example when you run JS in a browser it contains the window object. There would be no window object when you run JS in shell using cscript.exe

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated here, you should clarify your scenario. That said, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268320/execute-a-javascript-function-in-a-c-application) have an answer to how to run javascript from a .Net application.